# Expo app 'Your app is using the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)'

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, ads

I am trying to upload an app to the App Store and every time I upload a binary Apple insists that my app is using ads when I have never implemented such a thing. I reviewed the docs and removed all code involving `ASIdentifier` and `adIdentifier` I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. 
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expo docs for Deploying to App Stores: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/

> Apple will ask you whether your app uses the IDFA: the answer is "yes." This is because Expo contains the Facebook and Branch SDKs, which contain code for collecting the IDFA, and you'll need to check a couple boxes on the Apple submission form. See [Branch's Guide](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-submit-an-app-that-uses-an-idfa-to-the-app-store/) for which specific boxes to fill in.

Comment: Segment's guide no longer seems to have the specific boxes to fill in. Do you what they were @Zaytri ?

Comment: @magician11 updated with information from Expo's current docs

Comment: That guide seems out of date (2018). The new dialog that comes up asks: "Indicate how device IDs collected from this app are being used by you or your third-party partners (select all that apply):" with 6 checkboxes, and I can't continue until I check one of them. It's not clear to me which checkboxes to check.

Comment: @magician11 does this help? Because as of iOS 14, I'm not sure if IDFAs are a thing anymore: https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#app-privacy-questions