# "Does your app use an advertising ID?" for Expo

Tags: expo

I can't seem to find a clear answer as to how to answer this in the Google Play console.

Browsing the net I've found some answers related to advertising IDs

- "[How Expo Is Fooling Everyone](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-expo-is-fooling-everyone-adf7f34d7528)" has a comment from James Ide saying "If you are using the managed workflow, the standalone apps will contain the Google and Facebook SDKs."
- and [another stackoverflow post on the IDFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652516/expo-app-your-app-is-using-the-advertising-identifier-idfa).

My app doesn't use any specific type of advertising. But I think because I'm using Expo, I need to say yes to using an advertising ID because of the bundled Facebook SDK?

The form looks like this...

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know exactly how to fill out this form for an Expo app that has no advertising functionality added by the dev?

Comment: Great question, any thoughts?

Comment: Good question. I'm using the bare workflow and selected "no".

Comment: Great question.  I am also using the bareworkflow, so it would be great if anyone knows a definitive answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

The article [How Expo Is Fooling Everyone](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-expo-is-fooling-everyone-adf7f34d7528) states that *"all Expo applications collect the Advertising ID from users"* which is true for Expo SDKs up to version 45. This meant that in the past you had to select that an Advertising ID was used in both your Apple App Store and Google Play Store submissions.

However, as of `SDK 46` both the [Facebook](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/facebook/) and [FacbookAds](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/facebook-ads/) packages have been deprecated in favour of Expo's newer [EAS build service](https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60) and these packages now need to be included specifically by users if they want to include the functionality of Facebook's login or advertising platform.

The contentious issue with Expo has always been the inclusion of the Facebook package which is why, as the article referenced, all Expo apps prior to 46 needed the Advertising ID disclosure in app store submissions.

While I cannot find any conclusive confirmation from Expo's documentation, I no longer disclose any Advertising ID collection in my apps using Expo's `SDK 46+`. I recommend that most developers migrate to the newer SDKs (`SDK 47` as at time of writing this) to benefit from the EAS Build, updated React Native framework, and importantly, the removal of the default Facebook package included in every app.