# Expo SDK48 - Google Play Console - Advertising ID

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console, google-advertising-id

I upgraded expo to SDK48 and was trying to submit this to the Google Play Console.
Sadly im getting this error: **"Google Api Error: Invalid request - Your app targets Android 13 (API 33) or above. You must declare the use of advertising ID in Play Console."**. Is there a way to add this permission to expo and the Google Play Console?

Comment: you just need to declare the use of advertising ID in your Google Play Developer Console under **Policy and programs** -> **App content**

Comment: Thanks :) But my app is not doing anything with advertising. So I dont really understand why i should do this. @bagi2info.com

Comment: because expo library itself contains the Facebook and Branch SDKs, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652516/expo-app-your-app-is-using-the-advertising-identifier-idfa

Comment: Ah thanks. I actually tried your solution. You can tell google that you are not using advertising and it still works to submit the app for now.

Comment: Brent, one of the Expo team members said in Discord: "indeed, google shows that to everybody. so just fill out the declaration accordingly"

Comment: Stop telling people to go to Policy and programs -> App content – it doesn't exist.

Comment: Nick, I thought so too, but I just found it.  The left pane has more options than you think.  I'm from the era when a scrollbar would automatically appear when more content is below, but this is often no longer the case.  If you scroll down that left pane, you'll see Policy and Programs -> App Content.